# Interrupt test class at the first test failure

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have a JUnit 5 test consisting of multiple steps executing in order. The steps are defined in separate methods.

I want the tests to stop executing at first failure in the fixture/class.

This is behaviour which can be achieved in Spock by using `@Stepwise` annotation. I don't see how this can be done in JUnit 5.

Edit: added sample test

```java
@TestMethodOrder(Alphanumeric.class)
class MainTest {

    @Test void test1() {
        assertTrue(true);
        System.out.printf("%d test 1 - ok%n", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Test void test2() {
        assertTrue(false);
        System.out.printf("%d test 2 -nok%n", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Test void test3() {
        assertTrue(true);
        System.out.printf("%d test 3 - ok%n", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Test void test4() {
        assertTrue(true);
        System.out.printf("%d test 4 - ok%n", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Gives the following result:

```
1596054675044 test 1 - ok
1596054675075 test 2

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :true
Actual   :false

1596054675111 test 3 - ok
1596054675115 test 4 - ok
```

Comment: Put an assert at each step, JUnit stops execution at first assert failed

Comment: That's not the same thing. `@Stepwise` explicitly specifies in-order execution, which plain JUnit 5 doesn't.

Comment: @JiaSH, unfortunately, this is not right, as you can see in edited question, test failing in the middle does not stop following tests from executing.

Comment: @JiaSH I can confirm that execution does not stop at an assertion failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible to achieve this by adding JUnit5 annotation yet.

However, all infrastructure is there to implement your own extension, similar to one in [issue comment](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/48#issuecomment-522650226)

That works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using an assert in each step , because JUnit stops it's execution process when an assert failed.

Comment: I understand this requires marking test methods with different annotation than `@Test`?

Comment: I think the question is: Why have more than one @Test method when all depend on each other anyway. The answer implies that you move all steps into a single test method.

Comment: @johanneslink one reason would be to signify different steps for the tooling. Another reason is to have smaller more readable tests. I know you can emulate this for humans by code formatting, adding comments etc. but I find it as a terrible solution. You can solve the issue with Spock easily, I don't see why you couldn't do that with JUnit. I've seen a [proposal](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/48), but there is no final solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

If you want JUnit engine to stop running other `@Test` methods as soon as one of those fails, then it's ***not possible***.

JUnit Engine takes your fixture (Test class), and instantiates its *new* object per *each* @Test method, and note(!), that execution of those `@Test` methods are unpredictable to you. So, even if one `@Test` fails, `JUnit` needs to test other `@Test` methods and it will do so.

> Think about it from this perspective: If JUnit were to stop right after first failure, then how would it be possible to test what other units of your software are failing? say you have 1000 @Test methods, and 2nd fails, aren't you interested to test other 998 units?

Comment: Not really, I want to stop executing the next tests defined in the same test fixture. Think of a class as a kind of test scenario. It makes no sense to continue running the following tests.
I've already achieved predictable order since JUnit provides annotations for that (there is more than one way). One last thing to do is to stop execution of following tests in the fixture if there is a failure. There is an active [issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/48) but no complete solution yet.

Comment: So if you have 25 @Test cases in one fixture, and first fails, you want to finish the execution prematurely and don't test other cases? I think it makes absolutely perfect sense to test entire fixture. Can you show me which JUnit annotation gives you the order of Engine's execution?

Comment: It makes sense for regular unit tests which should be independent. For those, usually, I don't see a reason to run them in any particular order. However, if you have integration tests, the following tests often depend on what happened in previous steps. Running all of the tests, won't give meaningful results and will just make tests running longer. That's whats `@Stepwise` annotation in Spock for.

Comment: `Spock is a testing and specification framework..` - from spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M1/all_in_one.html; so it's not `JUnit`.

Comment: That's perfectly clear to me that JUnit isn't Spock. I'm just trying to achieve similar behaviour in one aspect mentioned in the question.

Comment: "JUnit...instantiates its new object per each Test method" - not when using TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS. Also, "execution of those Test methods are unpredictable to you" - not when using MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.

Comment: @GregBrown if you read the answer, it never touches anything you've mentioned. So, your argument "not when X" is not really applicable, because in "not when T", T can be several different things. E.g. not, when you don't use JUnit at all.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Your statements are misleading and inaccurate without clarification. And the original question is about JUnit, not about "not JUnit".

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri "Can you show me which JUnit annotation gives you the order of Engine's execution" - as shown in the OP's example, it is TestMethodOrder.

Comment: @GregBrown what I find misleading and inaccurate, is how you interpret my answer on whatever was asked. And I leave this here, avoiding long and opinion-based attitudes.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri "how you interpret my answer on whatever was asked" - that's how SO works. Your answer should be relevant to the question that was asked.