# Stop test execution after first fail

Tags: junit, junit5

I have to write a test divided into several steps. Each step is based on the previous one so if one fails, testing should be stopped.

```
@TestMethodOrder(AlphanumericOrder.class)
public class TestCase {

@Test
public void step10()  {
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
}

@Test
public void step20()  {
    Assertions.assertTrue(false);
}

@Test
public void step30()  {
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
}

@Test
public void step40()  {
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
}

}
```

In the example above testing should be terminated after step20(). I implemented custom MethodOrder to ensure correct sequence of execution. The problem I have is how to stop other tests after one fails? I tried to implement TestWatcher with no success. Is there any built-in mechanism in JUnit5 that can solve my problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036894/stopping-junit-suite-if-particular-test-fails

Comment: @Davide I tried this approach but it was not working as I expected.

Comment: @RolandWeisleder this is what I was looking for! Thank you very much for the link

Answer (score 0):

Working solution that was shared in the comments:

Reference: [Interrupt test class at the first test failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156759/interrupt-test-class-at-the-first-test-failure)

```
@ExtendWith(StepwiseExtension.class)
@TestMethodOrder(AlphanumericOrder.class)
public class TestCase {

    @Test
    public void step10()  {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void step20()  {
        Assertions.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void step30()  {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void step40()  {
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void before(){

    }

}

class StepwiseExtension implements ExecutionCondition, TestExecutionExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        ExtensionContext.Namespace namespace = namespaceFor(extensionContext);
        ExtensionContext.Store store = storeFor(extensionContext, namespace);
        String value = store.get(StepwiseExtension.class, String.class);
        return value == null ? ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("No test failures in stepwise tests") :
            ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled(String.format("Stepwise test disabled due to previous failure in '%s'", value));
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTestExecutionException(ExtensionContext extensionContext, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        ExtensionContext.Namespace namespace = namespaceFor(extensionContext);
        ExtensionContext.Store store = storeFor(extensionContext, namespace);
        store.put(StepwiseExtension.class, extensionContext.getDisplayName());
        throw throwable;
    }

    private ExtensionContext.Namespace namespaceFor(ExtensionContext extensionContext){
        return ExtensionContext.Namespace.create(StepwiseExtension.class, extensionContext.getParent());
    }


    private ExtensionContext.Store storeFor(ExtensionContext extensionContext, ExtensionContext.Namespace namespace){
        return extensionContext.getParent().get().getStore(namespace);
    }
}
```